# get object from mvc api using unity WWW

Tags: c#, web, asp.net-web-api, unity-game-engine

I don't know what im doing wrong here. Im trying to acces my webapi using WWW but it doesn't realy work.

Here is my webapi:

```
    [System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("api/Question")]
public class QuestionController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("GetQuestion")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetRandomQuestionByTheme(QuestionThemeRequest questionTheme)
    {
        try
        {
            if (questionTheme == null)
            {
                return this.Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "NOT OK");
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(questionTheme.QuestionTheme))
            {
                return this.Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "NOT OK");
            }
            var response = this.Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.Created, "It Worked!");
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public class QuestionThemeRequest
    {
        public string QuestionTheme { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is my unity code:

```
    public string GetQuestion(){
        string input = new QuestionThemeRequest(){ QuestionTheme = "MyRequest" }.ToString();
        Debug.Log (input.ToString());
        Hashtable headers = new Hashtable();
        headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        Debug.Log (headers.ToString ());
        byte[] body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (input);
        WWW www = new WWW ("http://localhost:52603/api/Question/GetRandomQuestionByTheme", body,     headers);
        Debug.Log (www.ToString ());
        //yield www;
        Debug.Log (www.text);
        if(www.error == "true"){
             Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        return "HEJSAN";

}
```

Im trying to do debug.log(www.text) to the request succeded but then i get a console error saying the request is not done yet.

Comment: You have to `yield` on the request. The request won't happen instantly, you have to wait for it to reach the server and return the response. Actually, you have to do exactly what you have commented out. Why is that commented out?

Comment: because if i don't unity gives me an error that www is already defined. :S

Comment: "a local variable named 'www' is already defined in this scope"

Comment: Actually, the yield statement is incomplete. It should read yield return www; and not yield www; Remove the comment, and add the keyword "return", and it should work

Comment: i got to have an IEnumerator as return type. And when i do add that i get this error:

Cannot convert `iterator' to delegate type `GameScript.GetQuestion()' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Answer (score 0):

You have commented out yield statement. You should write

```
yield return www;
```

[WWW reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerator GetQuestion(){
    string input = new QuestionThemeRequest(){ QuestionTheme = "MyRequest" }.ToString();
    Debug.Log (input.ToString());
    Hashtable headers = new Hashtable();
    headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    Debug.Log (headers.ToString ());
    byte[] body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (input);
    WWW www = new WWW ("http://localhost:52603/api/Question/GetRandomQuestionByTheme", body,     headers);
    yield return www;
    if(www.error != null){
         Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else {
         //do your stuff here 
    }
```

}

Comment: i got to have an IEnumerator as return type by some reason.

Comment: yield return www; 
This statement acts like a wait.
call  startcoroutine(GetQuestion()).. it would wait this the request is served.

In the else part you can start another function or do a callback to do pending tasks.